# i2c cable for 3ware 9650se and SuperChassis 846A-R1200B

Tags: raid, cable, 3ware, supermicro

What's the appropriate cable to support i2c (red LED drive indicator, failure) with this combination and what's the best way to order it? I see 3ware supports 846TQ but not 846A from http://kb.lsi.com/KnowledgebaseArticle15409.aspx?Keywords=supermicro+846

Bonus question, the cables to go from system board to back fans are too short, but the part seems to be sold out everywhere.

We're in Canada, our vendor has no expertise, I have tried to contact 3ware (LSI) and Supermicro.

Thanks!

---

I was told by LSI I need CBL-M8ML-06M to connect 9650SE-24M8 to the the Supermicro 846A (in a SuperChassis 846A-R1200B). However from end to end it is not clear what I require, I see mention of a Y-cable. I have been putting this off because it's annoying, now one of our drives have failed. Do you have any more info?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried to use a simple 4-pin cable from the I2C-MUX board to the 846TQ backplane, not the normal cable for the sideband connector and it worked. But the same cable and configuration did not work with the 846A backplane. I still wait for an answer from Supermicro about the difference of these two backplanes.

Comment: I received this response from raidsupport@lsi.com (LSI bought 3Ware):

  Looking at the manuals for the BPN-SAS-846A and the 826TQ it appears they use the same I2C connecters. You should be able to use that cable.

However we have not been able to order this part (assuming it works). One of our drives has failed and I'd like to swap it!